# Getting started with DB2 in c# / .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, db2

I have a simple question. 
I am trying to connect to a db2 database in c# and found this nuget package and added it to my project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/

nuget add package

```cs
using System;
using IBM.Data.DB2;

namespace db2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        // DB2Command MyDB2Command = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        }
    }
}
```

but as soon as I uncomment the db2 command it dotnet build failes with CS0246

> Program.cs(10,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace "DB2Command" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference? [c:\xxx\db2\db2.csproj]

Can anyone advice me how to resolve this? I am using vs code and the .net sdk 3.1

Thanks,

Alex

edit:

my db2.csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.3.0.100" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

also tried

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.3.0.100" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.3.0.100" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How exactly did you add the nuget reference? Can you check your `db2.csproj` file to see if it contains a `<PackageReference>` tag to the correct nuget package?

Comment: Hi, thanks I have edited my post

Comment: Can you try removing the `Sdk="..."` part of the Project tag and set `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp3.1`, and then running `dotnet restore --force`

Comment: I have changed this but when I try to build then i get an exception:  error MSB4040: Das Projekt enthält kein Ziel.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the new .csproj?

Comment: Yes, edited and updated

Comment: I found solution. Its releated to ibm dll. Solution is to using IBM.Data.DB2.Core; which is not documented imho.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Mind posting an answer ([answering your own questions is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) explaining what the problem was and detailing a solution? It might help out someone in the future

Comment: Yes of course. I have a meeting now and will do this afterwards. And thank you so much for your support

Comment: Just saw your edit to the comment. Very strange, even [IBMs own documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2CommandClass.html) says it should be in `IBM.Data.DB2`. May even be worth reporting it IBM

Comment: I don't think IBM has released official package for .Net core 3.1. Check this thread.

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=7be8e033-4c24-4de6-b52c-3db1647afe53&CommunityKey=ea909850-39ea-4ac4-9512-8e2eb37ea09a&tab=digestviewer&reply-inline=7be8e033-4c24-4de6-b52c-3db1647afe53&SuccessMsg=Thank%20you%20for%20submitting%20your%20message

Comment: sad but thanks for the interesting links